# How to allow users to add custom markers onto a blank map using Google maps API and Fire base

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an application on android studio that allows users to recommend restaurants and attractions they enjoy. They would submit it through a submission page on my ap. I would like it to store their submission in fire-base and then populate a blank map with a customer marker and the details.

I found a tutorial on adding custom markers to a map using users location that uses firebase but it all done within the code and I am unsure whether adjusting this code to fit my needs would be better than using a different method.

Below is the code used in the tutorial.

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_list, container, false);
    mUserListRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.user_list_recycler_view);
    mMapView = view.findViewById(R.id.user_list_map);

    initUserListRecyclerView();
    initGoogleMap(savedInstanceState);

    setUserPosition();

    return view;
}


private void addMapMarkers(){

    if(mGoogleMap != null){

        if(mClusterManager == null){
            mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<ClusterMarker>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mGoogleMap);
        }
        if(mClusterManagerRenderer == null){
            mClusterManagerRenderer = new MyClusterMarkerManagerRenderer(
                    getActivity(),
                    mGoogleMap,
                    mClusterManager
            );
            mClusterManager.setRenderer(mClusterManagerRenderer);
        }

        for(UserLocation userLocation: mUserLocations){

            Log.d(TAG, "addMapMarkers: location: " + userLocation.getGeo_point().toString());
            try{
                String snippet = "";
                if(userLocation.getUser().getUser_id().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())){
                    snippet = "This is you";
                }
                else{
                    snippet = "Determine route to " + userLocation.getUser().getUsername() + "?";
                }

                int avatar = R.drawable.cartman_cop; // set the default avatar
                try{
                    avatar = Integer.parseInt(userLocation.getUser().getAvatar());
                }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    Log.d(TAG, "addMapMarkers: no avatar for " + userLocation.getUser().getUsername() + ", setting default.");
                }
                ClusterMarker newClusterMarker = new ClusterMarker(
                        new LatLng(userLocation.getGeo_point().getLatitude(), userLocation.getGeo_point().getLongitude()),
                        userLocation.getUser().getUsername(),
                        snippet,
                        avatar,
                        userLocation.getUser()
                );
                mClusterManager.addItem(newClusterMarker);
                mClusterMarkers.add(newClusterMarker);

            }catch (NullPointerException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "addMapMarkers: NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage() );
            }

        }
        mClusterManager.cluster();

        setCameraView();
    }
}
private void setCameraView() {

    // Set a boundary to start
    double bottomBoundary = mUserPosition.getGeo_point().getLatitude() - .1;
    double leftBoundary = mUserPosition.getGeo_point().getLongitude() - .1;
    double topBoundary = mUserPosition.getGeo_point().getLatitude() + .1;
    double rightBoundary = mUserPosition.getGeo_point().getLongitude() + .1;

    mMapBoundary = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(bottomBoundary, leftBoundary),
            new LatLng(topBoundary, rightBoundary)
    );

    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(mMapBoundary, 0));}

private void setUserPosition() {

    for (UserLocation userLocation : mUserLocations) {
        if (userLocation.getUser().getUser_id().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())) {
            mUserPosition = userLocation;
        }
```

Comment: And what's wrong with this code?

Comment: This code picks up a users location and places a custom marker on the map. What I want is code that allows the customer to input their own data, assign this info to firebase and then populate a map